# Why is the Holder space with exponent $\alpha>1$ a constant set?

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

Why is the holder space with $\alpha >1$ a constant set? Is it related to the lipschitz condition? But, this seems to fail, as a continuous function may not be Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: See http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Holder-spaces.pdf Specifically, the remark near the beginning which ends with "That is why we do not talk about Hoelder spaces with Hoelder exponents larger than 1."

Comment: but what if u is just cts,not diff.??
the proof in the note seems require u to be diff.?

Comment: You don't have to assume f is differentiable, but you can prove that if it satisfies the holder inequality this forces the function to have derivative = 0. (See my answer)

Comment: oh...sorry ,i am so careless!!
thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\alpha > 1$, this implies that:
$$|f(y)-f(x)| \leq C\cdot|x-y|^\alpha$$
for some $C\in\Bbb R$

Then, we divide by $|x-y|$ on both sides:
$$\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|x-y|}\leq C\cdot|x-y|^{\alpha - 1}$$

But, this is just the absolute value of the difference quotient for $f$. Since $\alpha - 1 > 0$ and thus the right side of the inequality can be made as small as desired, we have that:
$$\lim_{y\to x}{\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}} = 0 \Rightarrow f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = D$$

for some constant $D\in\Bbb R$.